# Unable to install Splash onto Docker on Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, scrapy-splash

I am trying to install Splash onto docker but when doing so I get the error "Exec format error" but I am following the input directly from here: https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html

I am using Python version 3.5 on Ubuntu 16

[image: unb]

Comment: I just tried the above 2 commands on my workstation and it worked. Did you try to restart docker and check ?

Comment: Just ran service docker restart and get the same error

Comment: Can you try this on a 64-bit VM and report back?

Comment: 64bit resolved it!

Comment: @JarrattPerkins I'm going to add an answer just so we can mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a 64-bit host machine or VM to run the Splash docker image.